# Insert a variable with invalid characters into a div

Tags: javascript, html

I am needing to add what looks like an attribute into a div but I am not able to use the attribute tag because it has invalid characters. I can target the div by using

```
var ele = document.getElementById('divid');
```

But I then need to insert into the div tag a variable like this:

```
var topic = 'topic-Close=SCENARIO_COPIER_POPUP_CLOSE '
```

So I am wanting the div to look like

```
<div id="divid" topic-Close=SCENARIO_COPIER_POPUP_CLOSE> CONTENT OF DIV </div>
```

I am unable to use ele.setAttribute because of the invalid characters in the variable. Is there another way to add something to the DOM of a div dynamically that has invalid characters for an attribute tag?

Comment: *"I am unable to use ele.setAttribute because of the invalid characters in the variable."* What makes you say that? *What* is invalid, exactly?

Comment: Please note that `topic-Close` is an invalid attribute name. The spec defines no such attribute, and custom attributes on standard HTML elements must be prefixed with `data-`. If you use it, that makes your HTML invalid.

Comment: Despite it being invalid, I've never seen `setAttribute` refuse to do it. You should provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you can't, but you can add the attribute defined in that string via `setAttribute`:

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('divid');
var topic = 'topic-Close=SCENARIO_COPIER_POPUP_CLOSE ';
const [name, value] = topic.split("=", 2);
ele.setAttribute(name, value);

console.log(ele.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="divid"></div>
```

Note that:

- It's an invalid attribute. The spec doesn't define it, and custom attributes must start with [`data-`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).
- Attribute names are [not case-sensitive in HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2), so the browser may normalize it (for instance, Chrome shows it in lower case).

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. From the information OP presented this is your best shot. Just as a sidenote - custom attributes on autonomous custom element don't have the `data-` restriction.

Comment: @connexo - Thanks. And good point, because they define their own valid attributes.

Comment: Also good thing you pointed out the case-insensitivity of attribute names. This is obviously a necessary design decision with regard to `data-foo-bar` being converted to  `dataset.fooBar` in the element's API.

Answer (score -1):

Use data-attrName format for attribute name

```
ele.setAttribute("data-topic-Close", "SCENARIO_COPIER_POPUP_CLOSE")
```

Comment: There's no reason for `String.raw` here, and the OP seems to be starting with a string, not a string *literal*. To switch to using a template literal, they'd have to be using a literal to start with. *(not my downvote)*

Comment: I hv updated the answer